# On cygwin making(compiling) code the make command tell me I need 'ver' and 'type' command

Tags: c++, types, cygwin, freetype

I want make freetype in my cygwin, after I input make command

I:\freetype-2.4.4>make
make: ver: Command not found
make: type: Command not found
make: *** [dos_setup] Error 127

I don't know what is the ver and type command package name.
Someone can tell me I can add them in my cygwin system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeType docs specifically state that you should stay away from CygWin, preferring MinGW instead.

That seems to be confirmed by the fact that `ver` and `type` are *Windows* commands, and MinGW is UNIX executables under Windows rather than UNIX executables running under the CygWin DLL emulation environment.

So, here's the install process I used.

1. Go to [SourceForge MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20101030/) and get the latest installer, `mingw-get-inst-20101030.exe`. Run this.
2. Choose the defaults for everything except the package selection (you have to accept the GPL of course). When it asks which packages you want, ask for them all.
3. Let it install.
4. Once done, open up the control panel, choose `System`, select the `Advanced` tab, click on the `Environment Variables` button, then change your path to append `;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`. Exit the control panel.
5. Open up a command window and go to the directory where you unpacked `ft244.zip`.
6. Run `make` (may need to do this twice).

And that should work:

```
C:\freetype-2.4.4> make
gcc -ansi -pedantic  -I./objs -I./builds/win32 -I./include -c -g -O3 -Wall 
    -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H="<ftmodule.h>"
    -o objs/ftsystem.o src/base/ftsystem.c
gcc -ansi -pedantic  -I./objs -I./builds/win32 -I./include -c -g -O3 -Wall 
    -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H="<ftmodule.h>"
    -o objs/ftdebug.o src/base/ftdebug.c
: : :
<<snip>>
: : :
del .\objs\freetype.a 2> nul
make: [objs/freetype.a] Error 127 (ignored)
ar -r objs/freetype.a  ./objs/ftsystem.o ./objs/ftdebug.o ./objs/ftinit.o
      ./objs/ftbase.o ./objs/ftbbox.o ./objs/ftbdf.o ./objs/ftbitmap.o
      ./objs/ftcid.o ./objs/ftfstype.o ./objs/ftgasp.o ./objs/ftglyph.o
      ./objs/ftgxval.o ./objs/ftlcdfil.o ./objs/ftmm.o ./objs/ftotval.o
      ./objs/ftpatent.o ./objs/ftpfr.o ./objs/ftstroke.o ./objs/ftsynth.o
      ./objs/fttype1.o ./objs/ftwinfnt.o ./objs/ftxf86.o ./objs/truetype.o
      ./objs/type1.o ./objs/cff.o ./objs/type1cid.o ./objs/pfr.o
      ./objs/type42.o ./objs/winfnt.o ./objs/pcf.o ./objs/bdf.o
      ./objs/sfnt.o ./objs/autofit.o ./objs/pshinter.o ./objs/raster.o
      ./objs/smooth.o ./objs/ftcache.o ./objs/ftgzip.o ./objs/ftlzw.o
      ./objs/psaux.o ./objs/psnames.o
C:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe: creating objs/freetype.a

C:\freetype-2.4.4> _
```

Comment: I really did in cygwin bash 
which make give me correct fedback
/usr/bin/make
but the problem is there is still error 
make: ver: Command not found 
make: type: Command not found 
make: * [dos_setup] Error 127
I do not know why
the package name is ft244.zip
you can find it on http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/

Answer (score 4):

maybe it would help you.

```
mingw32-make SHELL=cmd
```